# How to charge shipping in WP e-commerce based on a variant?

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have a client that wants to charge different shipping rates based on a size variant (small,  medium, large).

She does not have the weights or size in inches of each item, she only wants to assign the shipping for each item based on whether the shopper chooses small, medium, large or extra large for the size of the item.

Is there a way to assign a shipping price in WP e-commerce using a variant and still have it show as the shipping cost?

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://docs.getshopped.org/documentation/creating-variations/

> Picture this: James wants to create a store to sell T-shirts. Once he
>   starts building his product catalog, he realizes that he needs a way
>   for customers to specify what size shirt they want. He shudders to
>   think that he might need to create a separate product listing for each
>   size of each shirt. Not only would that be extremely time-consuming,
>   it would be confusing for potential customers. Isn’t there an easier
>   way? Yes! **Variations** are exactly what James needs. **By creating a
>   variation for size**, he can create one listing for each shirt and have
>   **customers simply choose a size from a drop-down list**. As an added
>   benefit, **if he needs to charge extra for an irregular size, variations
>   can handle that**, too.

Beyond that,

There is [this wp-ecommerce core filter](http://docs.getshopped.org/documentation/wpsc_cart_shipping-filter/) `Located in: cart.class.php`;

```
function wpsc_cart_shipping() {
   global $wpsc_cart;
   return apply_filters( 'wpsc_cart_shipping', wpsc_currency_display( $wpsc_cart->calculate_total_shipping() ) );
}
```

Which means you could filter the price based on a variable,

```
function my_variable_price(){
   //do your logic here
   //based on size selected
}
add_filter('wpsc_cart_shipping', 'my_variable_price');
```

This is intended as a guide, not a 1:1 solution, since your problem is localized to your use-case, we'd need more information about how you are setting size options. Whether its held in post meta, or via some other means. But, I'd seriously look into the first link provided before going down this path.

Comment: THe link is just what I have tried.  It is very easy to implement, but it changes the price of the item and the shipping does not reflect a change in price.  I know that's anal, but the client wants the price of the item to remain constant and change the shipping based on the size.  I will talk to her today about assigning a base shipping price (like the shipping price for a small item) and just adding to the cost of the actual item fi a larger size is chosen.

Comment: In order to properly calculate shipping in the code, you'd need to cycle through all of the items in the cart, and add the shipping charges based on each item's size.  I'm not sure I'm up to that.  It sure would be nice to have the ability to assign shipping costs based on a variable that actually showed the amount as a change in shipping costs - not by varying the item's price.

Comment: @user21398 If the standard variations method as provided in the first link doesn't extend to allow for your clients use-case then you'll definitely need to be working with action hooks and filters to get the job done (as shown above). If that's beyond what you can do currently, I'd suggest outsourcing the task, unless someone who already has wp-ecommerce installed is kind enough to write and test an example filter based on said requirements. I *may* investigate further during the week when time permits. But I do agree that it would be nice to have that ability overall.